# Что лучше mixins sass или классы html

Tags: css, bootstrap, seo, sass, mixins

bootstrap 4 дает мне выбор верстать по сетке через **html** классы

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

или **sass** миксины

```
div
    +make-container
    +make-container-max-widths()
    div 
        +make-row()
        div 
          +media-breakpoint-down(md)
              +make-col(3)
```

и вопрос в том что считается лучшим для ***сео***, и вообще что *удобнее*,
какой подход выбрать?

Ведь при втором методе файл css становиться более весомым чем при первом варианте!

Comment: Различия в сео я так понимаю никакой, ведь код все-равно генерируется хтмлный

Comment: @Duoxx, html  не генерируется, миксины сасс создают css, а не html

Comment: _при втором методе файл css становиться более весомым чем при первом варианте!_ - по сравнению с чем?

Comment: при перво варианте когда пишешь классы в html при этом css мы не трогаем , а при верстке миксинами компилируется медиа запросы @Grundy, плюс css становиться больше от того что туда пишется больше стилей, и в итоге мы стаим перед выбором у нас либо html болше либо css !!!!

Comment: какой именно css ты считаешь?

Comment: тот где я пишу стили ) main.css

Comment: А почему только его? :-) в этом и ошибка :)

Comment: ясно нужно отверстать сайт в двух вариантах а потом их взвесить )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Миксины позволяют *собрать свой собственный* бутстрап, в котором будет только необходимое, а также поменять различные переменные, вроде количества колонок, либо количество и значения breakpoints и т.д.

В связи с этим не будет нужды подключать основной файл bootstrap.css

---

Исходя из этого стоит осуществлять выбор подхода:

если нет нужды в специальной настройке и используется множество классов из уже существующих, а также если нужен быстрый прототип - стоит выбирать стандартную комплектацию

в противном случае можно потратить время на вычленение только нужных инструментов.